# WinForms DateTimePicker to Selected Cell from DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview

I am new to WinForms and am trying to make an application that will hold certain data in a DataGridView Style.
Now I've managed to create the app where if clicked on a cell the TextBoxes and the ComboBox get populated with data from the GridView, but I am now struggling to get the DateTimePicker to do the same...
Bellow you will see the code I am using to call the data back into the text and combo boxes, but I am missing the proper call for the DateTimePicker and I don't know how to call it properly

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    index = e.RowIndex;
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
    textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    dateTimePicker1.Value = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    comboBox1.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    textBox2.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
}
```

I am aware I can't convert type string to System.DateTime, but I don't know how I can do that...

Thank you in advance.

So to answer your question JohnG,
My current code adds a row of data into the Grid:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, dateTimePicker1.Value, comboBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        }
```

The issue occurs when i add a new row, the date in the DateTime value cell updates for all rows, something i do not want.
Hope this helps.

**Correction, it updates only the selected row, while it creates a new row.**

Comment: Typically, you would “bind” those controls to the grids `DataSource` and your code becomes unnecessary. Does the grid use a data source?

Comment: Well the data source is what i input in the App itself, but it does not pull any data, still too new to even attempt that to be honest.

Comment: `DataSource` _can_ be something more complex like enumerating `DataTable`  where queries are pulled from a database. But it works with a variety of collections including simple `List` or `Array` (one-way binding) or `BindingList` (two way). My suggestion would be to try out those simple sources first to experiment with how binding works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, you may note that the code uses a `DataSource` to the grid. And I highly recommend you do the same regardless if the grid is initially empty and is only expecting data to be input by the user. In other words, it will simplify things in many-many ways.

So, if I have this correct, you have a grid, and some “external” text boxes, a date time picker and a combo box on a form. The columns in the grid have some values like name, date and some other values. And… is what you want is that when the user selects a cell/row in the grid… then… the “external” text boxes, date time picker and combo box will contain the same values as the selected row in the grid.

I will assume you want the user to be able to “edit” the text box and have it also update the grid’s cell and vice versa. If this is the case, then the example below uses this approach.

This is fairly trivial with a text box or date time picker… however a combo box is a little more work and you do not specify “how” you are currently adding items to the combo box. In other words, if the user is entering data into the grid and they get to cell 2 (the combo box value) you have the following code…

```
comboBox1.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
```

This is a little odd in a sense that the value the user types into the cell will be “ignored” unless the value actually exists in the combo boxes list of items. In other words, this implies some pre-thought about what items are in the combo boxes list of items. If the grids cell 2 was itself a combo box cell, then this may change things, however, you would STILL have to do extra work to fill the combo boxes list of items.

Unfortunately, even with a combo box cell…, “binding” the combo boxes value from the grid to an “external” regular combo box is not as easy as it may appear. If the combo boxes list of items in the grid were simply `strings` AND the “external” regular combo boxes list of items was simply `strings`, then this is doable. However, this is rarely the case and it would still involve something similar to your current approach. Because of this, I will leave out the “external” combo box for now.

The example below shows how to “bind” the “external” `TextBoxes` and `DateTimePicker`. We will use a simple `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid. In addition, we will also use this same `DataTable` as a `DataSource` when we “bind” the text boxes and date time picker. A better approach is to use a `BindingSource` and will update this later.

First let us get some test data for the grid. The grid will have four columns: First Name, Last Name, Hire Date and Department. The Hire Date is a column of type `DateTime` and all others are of a `string` type. The method below will return a `DataTable` showing the columns described above…

```
private DataTable GetDataForGrid() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Dept", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Hire Date", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Rows.Add("Joe", "Fowler", "Accounting", DateTime.Now);
  dt.Rows.Add("Sally", "Field", "Human Resources", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
  dt.Rows.Add("John", "Houston", "Management", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
  dt.Rows.Add("Jack", "Black", "Contractor", DateTime.Now.AddDays(3));
  dt.Rows.Add("Tony", "Curtis", "Production", DateTime.Now.AddDays(4));
  return dt;
}
```

In the forms scope, we will create a global variable `GridDT` and set it using the method above. Then we will use the `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid. The forms `Load` event may look something like…

```
DataTable GridDT;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridDT = GetDataForGrid();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridDT;
}
```

This should display the grid like below…

[image]

If you run this code, you will not see the text boxes and date time picker with the same values as the selected row. We still need to add the “binding” code for the controls like below…

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridDT = GetDataForGrid();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridDT;
  textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", GridDT, "First Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "");
  textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", GridDT, "Last Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "");
  dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Value", GridDT, "Hire Date", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "");
}
```

The `DataBindings.Add` is self-explanatory, however the documentation can be found at [Control.DataBindings Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

If you run the code now, you will note the text boxes change values when the user selects different rows in the grid. It should also be noted that this is a “slow” kind of a two-way binding. Example; If you change the “external” first name text box… then you will NOT see this change “immediately” in the grid. Depending on what control you click on, the change may not be reflected in the grid. If you click on another text box or press the Tab key… the change may not show in the grid.

The same idea applies to the grid. If the user changes the text in the first name cell, then those changes will NOT be “immediately” reflected into the “external” text box until the user selects a “different” ROW in the grid. If the user presses the Tab key or clicks on another cell in the SAME row… then the changes will NOT be reflected in the external text boxes.

This presents a little problem from a user stand point. IMO… I WANT to “see” those changes at least when the user either edits and leaves the cell in the grid OR if the user edits and leaves an “external” text box. To fix this, I will use a `BindingSource` instead of a `DataTable` as the `DataSource`.

After we switch to the `BindingSource`, you will not see much change and the previous problems persist. However, this will simplify our solution to the previous problem. 1) We will wire up the “external” text boxes `Leave` event to execute the `BindingSources` `EndEdit()` method to update the grid. 2) we will wire up the grids `CellValueChanged` event to do the same to update the external text boxes. 3) we will use the date time pickers `Leave` event to do the same.

Note I used the same `Leave` event for both text boxes. These final changes are below….

```
BindingSource GridBS;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  textBox1.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox_Leave);
  textBox2.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox_Leave);
  dateTimePicker1.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox_Leave);
  dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);

  GridBS = new BindingSource();
  GridBS.DataSource = GetDataForGrid();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridBS;
  textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", GridBS, "First Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "");
  textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", GridBS, "Last Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, "");
  dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add("Value", GridBS, "Hire Date", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, ""); 
}


private void textBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridBS.EndEdit();
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  GridBS.EndEdit();
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: I will give this a shot when i get the time, thank you very much.
And i'll see how i can implement this into my own project.

Comment: Ok, so yes this technically solves my problem, but now i've encountered another one, see when i bind the data value whenever i insert a new value through a button click the first value for the DateTime in the table changes from the original value to the new one, and i do not want that... Is there a way to circumvent that?

Comment: I have figured it out... i just added:
dateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Clear();
Thank you very much JohnG!!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are describing. The code is adding a row? And the DateTime gets changed when you add this row? Please can you edit your question and “add” this code that adds a row? Please do not add the code as a comment. Please edit your question and add it to the bottom.

Comment: Hmmm… are you sure clearing the binding is what you want to do? You will have to re-bind it somewhere down the line if you want it to still change when the user selects a row in the grid. Sorry if I am missing something, but it seems odd to remove the binding simply to add a new row.

Answer (score 0):

The type of [`DateTimePicker.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value?view=netframework-4.6) is [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.6).
In order to initialize a `DateTime` object, you can use one of the following:

1. [`DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.6) - Returns the `DateTime`. May throw an exception if the string format is not valid.
2. [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.6) - Updates a `DateTime` **out** parameter. Returns false if the string format is not valid.

However - since `DateTimePicker.Value` is a property, it cannot be passed as an `out` parameter. If you want to parse directly into it, use the `Parse` as you can see below. Alternatively you can use `TryParse` to parse into a local variable and then assign the propety to it.

Example using `Parse`:

```
string date_time_string;  // initialized from your data grid or in any other way
try
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(date_time_string);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle parsing error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on JohnG's excellent comment, using binding not only solves the `DateTime` formatting issue; it provides the added benefit of inline editing using date/time pickers and combo boxes within the `DataGridView` itself.

[image: Inline editing]

If you'd like to try this approach, make a class to represent a `Row` in the view.

```
class Record
{
    public string Description { get; set; } = $"Item {autoName++}";
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public CBValues Value { get; set; } = CBValues.Apple;

    static char autoName = 'A';
}

enum CBValues
{
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Banana,
}
```

Next make a `BindingList<Record>` of them...

```
BindingList<Record> Records = new BindingList<Record>();
```

and set it as the `DataSource` of your `DataGridView` in this initialization method which also installs the custom columns (the `CalendarColumn` class is copied from this Microsoft [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN)).

```
private void InitializeDataGridView()
{
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

    // Bind the list of records to the DataGridView
    dataGridView1.DataSource = Records;

    // Add one or more records to autogenerate the Columns
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) Records.Add(new Record());

    // Swap autogenerated column for CalendarColumn.
    dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.Date)]);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(
        // This class is copied from Microsoft example.
        new CalendarColumn
        {
            Name = nameof(Record.Date),
            DataPropertyName = nameof(Record.Date),
        });

    // Swap autogenerated column for DataGridViewComboboxColumn.
    dataGridView1.Columns.Remove(dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.Value)]);
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(
        new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
        {
            Name = nameof(Record.Value),
            DataPropertyName = nameof(Record.Value),
            DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CBValues)),
        });

    // Format columns
    dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.Description)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    dataGridView1.Columns[nameof(Record.Date)].Width = 150;
}
```

*If you choose **not** to use inline editing, here's your handler code modified to use binding:*

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var record = Records[e.RowIndex];
    textBox1.Text = record.Description;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = record.Date;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex= (int)record.Value;
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/dgv-with-date-picker-and-combo.git) this sample.